# Android styles.xml windowNoTitle (ActionBarActivity)

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I want to hide the title bar (where the activity tile is shown) in my application. I'm doing this by setting the `android:windowNoTitle` item to `true`. This works fine for devices with API level 19. I tested it with a device running API level 10 and it only hides the notification bar. The tile bar is still shown.

Here is my `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

EDIT: I'm using the `AppBaseTheme` as the theme in my manifest. There are no other styles.xml files in any other value-vXX folder.

Edit#2: I'm extending an `ActionBarActivity` for my activity.

Comment: add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before setContentView(layout) in your onCreate() method.
and For full screen use `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);'

Comment: same result. not working under gingerbread.

Comment: It seems you are using **2 different theme names** (`AppTheme` and `AppBaseTheme`). And the themes **don't differ**. So, not only it's useless to have 2 themes, but the names should be identical.

Comment: @DerGolem ok. I tried it with one theme (only the `AppBaseTheme`). Stil not working

Comment: I use 1 theme for all the devices and it works perfectly on API level 8 to 16 (since I only have 5 physical devices). I'm sure it's working on 17-19 devices too

Comment: @DerGolem I'm using now only one styles.xml with only one theme and it doesn't work. Only the full screen mode seems to work on gingerbread

Comment: In your Manifest file (in the application section), is there a line like `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`?

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, `AppBaseTheme`, because I deletet the other one. And as said, it works on api level 19, without any settings in the `Activity`.

Comment: Very strange. It MUST work... Did you remove the other themes/styles in your `values-xy` folders?

Comment: @DerGolem yes. There's only one values.xml file.

Comment: I find it really surprising. Try doing a Project/Clean. Then you can try an Eclipse restart.

Comment: @DerGolem Done: clean + restart + clean => install. no changes.

Comment: Did you also add the suggested code by Kunu?

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, I tried that. same result. PS: updated the Question to the new situation.

Comment: Try using this line: `parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` instead of `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` (I just compared it with my **working** theme).

Comment: @DerGolem This won't work for me, because I use a `ActionBarActivity` and that needs a `AppCompat` theme.

Comment: But the AppCompat theme is **NOT full screen**, by definition. So, the StatusBar will go away, but not the TitleBar

Comment: @DerGolem so there's no way around extending an standard Activity?

Comment: @DerGolem But why does it work then on api level 19?

Comment: I don't uderstand if you need the ActionBar or not...

Comment: @DerGolem No, just using it because it was added by default.

Comment: `just using it because it was added by default` - Bad practice! I'd remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, I will do so. I thought this was "the new way of doing it" and an standard `Activity` doesn't get used any more. Thanks ;)

Comment: No, no... don't bloat your apps with `unneeded` and `unwanted` things.

Comment: I have a Header Bar and a Footer Bar, but these are simply RelativeLayouts I implemented **my own**. And still have the freedom of using the whole screen surface.

Comment: @DerGolem Woud you mind posting this as answer?

Comment: OK, it took me a while to collect the comments and make asenseful answer out of them... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 1 theme for all the devices and it works perfectly on API level 8 to 16 (since I only have 5 physical devices). I'm sure it's working on 17-19 devices too.

Make sure that in your Manifest file (in the application section), there is a line like android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Try using this for your theme:

```
<style
    name="AppBaseTheme"
    parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    ...

</style>
```

And remove the styles/themes in the `values-xy` folders

**[EDIT]**

Since the AppCompat theme is NOT full screen, by definition, the StatusBar will go away, but not the TitleBar

If you don't need the ActionBar offered by the AppCompat, then you should get rid of the AppCompat as soon as possible:  don't bloat your apps with `unneeded` and `unwanted` things

For instance, I have a Header Bar and a Footer Bar, but these are simply RelativeLayouts I implemented my own.
And still have the freedom of using the whole screen surface.

Answer (score 16):

try using this

> ```
> <style name="MyMaterialDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
> </style>
> ```

remove android prefix!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` in styles.xml but I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

So I followed the advise to stick to the AppCompat theme, and could hide statusbar and actionbar using the following lines in `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```