# Before Activity comes live, can't hide statusBar in the application scope in Android

Tags: android

In the application I am working on it's required to have completely transparent statusBar. I am able to hide the statusBar perfectly from the LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY but there is still sometime before the activity appears there is like one second where I still can see the statusBar not transparent and once the onCreate function/method of the LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY gets executed, it makes the statusBar completely transparent.

I need to be able to control the status bar during that time, I guess the only place in the code where I can take action is the Application class but how to access the UI there?

Comment: why not load the status bar when required ? Keep it `VISIBILITY_GONE` when loading the app

Comment: where should I do so, the problem I facing in any solution is that all solutions are made for activity where u have complete control over status bar but before it appears comes the problem, I don't know how to control anything

Comment: it will be better if you can post the code chunk with you question

Comment: I don't have any problem with the code, I just don't know where to put it but here is the link I am just copy pasting from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Comment: I used the first solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Put `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your theme.

**Explanation**

It will prevent the title bar from loading, so you don't have to hide it in your code.

If you are directly using a theme from Android, you can go to your `themes.xml` and extend the theme you are using and use that one in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<style name="<EnterYourTheme>.CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <!-- EDIT (how to do it for the action bar) -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

[**Source**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708951)

Comment: Works but I want a similar one for the navigation/system bar, can u help me with this